# OpenGL Deferred Rendering not working

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, deferred-rendering

I try to render my geometry in the first pass and render it from a buffer to a quad in my second pass.
Rendering the geometry directly to screen works, but as soon as I try to render to the quad with multiple passes, the screen stays black (the clear-color is grey).
I think my shader might be the problem. Please just ask for more code if needed.

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 440

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vertexNormal;

centroid out vec2 UV;
out vec4 position;
out vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 uniMatModel;
uniform mat4 uniMatView;
uniform mat4 uniMatProjection;
uniform mat4 uniMatModelView;
uniform mat4 uniMatModelViewProjection;
uniform mat3 uniMatNormal;

void main()
{
    UV = vertexUV;
    position = uniMatModelView * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
    normal = normalize(uniMatNormal * vertexNormal);
    gl_Position = uniMatModelViewProjection * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 440

centroid in vec2 UV;
in vec4 position;
in vec3 normal;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;
layout (location = 1) out vec3 positionData;
layout (location = 2) out vec3 normalData;
layout (location = 3) out vec3 colorData;

subroutine void renderPassType();
subroutine uniform renderPassType renderPass;

uniform sampler2D uniSamTexture;
uniform sampler2D uniSamAlpha;

layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D positionTex;
layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D normalTex;
layout(binding = 2) uniform sampler2D colorTex;

subroutine (renderPassType)
void renderWorld()
{
    if (texture2D(uniSamAlpha, UV).rgb[0] == 1.0) // Alphamaps have to be inverted!
    {
        discard;
        colorData = vec3(0.0);
    }
    else
    {
        colorData = texture2D(uniSamTexture, UV).rgb;
    }

    positionData = vec3(position.x, position.y, position.z);
    normalData = normal;
}

subroutine (renderPassType)
void renderLight()
{
    fragColor = vec4(texture(colorTex, UV).rgb, 1.0);
}

void main()
{
    renderPass();
}
```

**Edit:**

```
void C0::Cocaine::makeFBO(GLuint &fbo)
{
    GLuint depthBuf;
    Texture
        posTex(this),
        normTex(this),
        colorTex(this)
    ;

    // Create and bind the FBO
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    // The depth buffer
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuf);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuf);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, static_cast<GLsizei>(resolution.x), static_cast<GLsizei>(resolution.y));

    // Create the textures for position, normal and color
    posTex.createGBuf(GL_TEXTURE0, GL_RGB32F, static_cast<int>(resolution.x), static_cast<int>(resolution.y));
    normTex.createGBuf(GL_TEXTURE1, GL_RGB32F, static_cast<int>(resolution.x), static_cast<int>(resolution.y));
    colorTex.createGBuf(GL_TEXTURE2, GL_RGB8, static_cast<int>(resolution.x), static_cast<int>(resolution.y));

    // Attach the textures to the framebuffer
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuf);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, posTex.getTextureID(), 0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, normTex.getTextureID(), 0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTex.getTextureID(), 0);

    GLenum drawBuffers[] = { GL_NONE, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2 };
    glDrawBuffers(4, drawBuffers);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

```
void C0::Texture::createGBuf(GLenum texUnit, GLenum format, int width, int height)
{
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
    glActiveTexture(texUnit);
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, format, width, height);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
}
```

**Edit:** The render method:

```
void C0::Mesh::render()
{
    if (shader != nullptr)
    {
        shader->use();
        shader->setModelMatrix(modelMatrix);
    }

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    if (!is2D)
    {
        for (int i = 0x1; i <= 0xB; i++)
        {
            if (texture[i] != nullptr)
            {
                glBindMultiTextureEXT(GL_TEXTURE0 + i, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]->getTextureID());
            }
        }
    }

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, indexCount);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

More code:

```
pass1->setRenderCallback([&]() {

    sp->useSubRoutine(srp1);
    cube->render();

    return true;
});

pass2->setRenderCallback([&]() {

    sp->useSubRoutine(srp2);
    sp->resetMatrices(); // it should be a 2D quad, so I reset the MVP uniforms to 1.0f
    sp->lockMVP(true); // workaround (still playing around with everything)
    dq->render(); // render display quad
    sp->lockMVP(false);

    return true;
});

e->setOnRender([&]() {

    pass1->render();
    pass2->render();

    /* handle input etc... */
});
```

Pass render method:

```
bool Pass::render()
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    if (depthTest)
    {
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }
    else
    {
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }

    if (onRender != nullptr)
    {
        if (!onRender())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (fbo != 0)
    {
        glFinish();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please **do not** edit your question to fix the problems pointed out in the answers. It invalidates the answers.

Comment: Have you checked if the seperate images are rendered correctly?

Comment: @RetoKoradi: It is not the answer...

Comment: @AntonD: what do you mean by separate images?

Comment: @MarcoAlka Normally when writing a deferred renderer you render to multiple images in the first pass, and then use those images to create a final image in the second pass. Examples of those images are the color texture, the normal texture, the position texture  and others. As a debugging step you can render those seperate images to the screen to test if the first pass was succesfull. Could you give more info about your implementation?

Comment: @AntonD: It seems the buffers are empty (black screen). I added the methods which create the FBO and the GBuffer.

Comment: You're setup code seems ok, are you selecting the right subroutine when rendering? What happens when you make the output in the shaders a constant value like white? If the resulting textures are white, then something must be wrong with the way you render things.

Comment: Even when I make the first pass write white as color, I can only see the clear color (grey). I added the render method for meshs. It is used for everything (scene and quad).

Comment: I don't see you selecting the right subroutine when rendering. You can read more about subroutines here: www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-core-tutorial/glsl-core-tutorial-subroutines/

Comment: Yeah, because this is not the entire rendercode but only for my meshes.  If you need the rest of the code (switching subroutines, firing the render methods, using glFinish(), etc. , I will post it later when I am at home.

Comment: Since it is very hard to debug without having acces to code I would suggest the following steps. First try to simplify your shader by temporarily removing the subroutines and instead make the output always equal to white ( vec4(1,1,1,1) ). If you don't see a thing, then your error must be in your setup code. Otherwise your error must be in the code which sets up the uniforms/ attributes. Also have you checked for opengl errors and checked if the framebuffer was completed?

Comment: I see the quad, so my screen will turn white. There are no openGL errors. I am already using a debug context. The framebuffer should complete since I call `glFinish()` after the first and second pass.

Answer (score 2):

With the shader version string you use:

```
#version 440
```

the default for the profile is `core`. From the GLSL 4.40 spec:

> A profile argument can only be used with version 150 or greater. If no profile argument is provided and the version is 150 or greater, the default is **core**.

The `texture2D()` function you are calling in the fragment shader is only available in the compatibility profile. In the core profile, you need to use the overloaded `texture()`:

```
if (texture(uniSamAlpha, UV).rgb[0] == 1.0) // Alphamaps have to be inverted!
...
    colorData = texture(uniSamTexture, UV).rgb;
```

If you have problems with your shaders, it's always a good idea to check that the compilation was successful. You can use the following calls for this:

```
glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, ...);
glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId, ...);
```

Comment: The shaders compile and link successfully without any errors or warnings. Changing the texture2D() function to texture() did not solve the problem.

Comment: It probably wouldn't have compiled on all platforms. Some GLSL compilers ignore a lot of errors, but others don't.

Answer (score -2):

glDrawBuffers has a GL_NONE even though you are using a renderbuffer for depth.
Remove it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That answer is not unclear, but false. The draw buffer state only affects color attachments, for rendering to a depth attachment, `GL_NONE` for draw buffers is perfectly fine.